# Passing one api parameters value to another api

Tags: jmeter

In JMeter I have two Api , one api generate filename and id then these parameters pass to another api here I used plugin path extractor and also use csv data set config to extract , save and pass parameters and its value to another api but problem is when multiple user it generate multiple filename and id but how to pass those file name and id to every httprequest to another api.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any CSV Data Set Config, it will be sufficient to

1. Add a suitable [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) to extract the generated file name
2. The Post-Processor will store the generated name into a JMeter Variable
3. You should be able to use the variable in the "2nd API"

As per [JMeter Documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) `Variables are local to a thread` so each thread (virtual user) you define in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) will have its own value.

Demo:

[image]

More information on JMeter Correlation concept: [Advanced Load Testing Scenarios with JMeter: Part 1 - Correlations](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-1-correlations)

Answer (score 0):

If you stumbled on this like me then @Dmitri T's answer is almost there but missing a step.

1. Add a suitable [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) to extract the generated file name
2. The Post-Processor will store the generated name into a JMeter
   Variable
3. Create a [BeanShell Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-jmeter#:%7E:text=Beanshell%20Assertion%20%E2%80%93%20An%20advanced%20assertion,code%20during%20a%20sampler%20run.) and add the following in the `script`
   block: `${__setProperty(<varNameYouWant>, ${varSavedFromStep})}`
4. You should be able to use the variable from any thread group

[image: Post processor to get the property (in my case it was a JSON property)]

[image: Bean Shell Assertion]